# Не приходят платежи на кошелек blockchain

Tags: php, bitcoin, blockchain

Добрый вечер, есть задача реализовать прием криптовалюты через сайт.
Решил использовать blockchain.info

1. Зарегистрировался в системе
2. Запросил ключ доступа для работы с API
3. Сделал все по инструкции https://blockchain.info/api/api_receive

Моя функция для работы с сервисом

```
public function receive($callback)
{
    $request = file_get_contents('https://api.blockchain.info/v2/receive?' . 'xpub=' . $this->xpub . '&callback=' . urlencode($callback) . '&key=' . $this->api_key . '&gap_limit=' . $this->gap_limit);
    $blockchain = json_decode($request, TRUE);
    return $blockchain;
}
```

Проблема в том, что при выполнении запроса, я получаю сгенерированный адрес кошелька

```
[address] => 199eCo1DUc3X1hKhV8wktP1FL1PynNXgY4
```

на который нужно переслать денежку.
Но приотправке деньги не засчитались на баланс в ЛК (blockchain).

Вот первый лог который лог из callback

```
{"secret":"ZzsMLGKe162CfA5EcG6j","address":"199eCo1DUc3X1hKhV8wktP1FL1PynNXgY4","transaction_hash":"36da7e3523c6a3752839979dc9905621664538b77ded18651cefd35c54762a56","value":"3209","confirmations":"0"}
```

Потом пришел еще один

```
{"secret":"ZzsMLGKe162CfA5EcG6j","address":"199eCo1DUc3X1hKhV8wktP1FL1PynNXgY4","transaction_hash":"36da7e3523c6a3752839979dc9905621664538b77ded18651cefd35c54762a56","value":"3209","confirmations":"1"}
```

Но деньги так и не засчитались на баланс, хотя транзакция уже подтверждена 
https://blockchain.info/tx/36da7e3523c6a3752839979dc9905621664538b77ded18651cefd35c54762a56

Подскажите, в чем может быть дело, почему баланс не обновился в ЛК?

Comment: У провайдера-то спрашивали? Если есть 117 подтверждений, значит транзакция точно настоящая и прошла, в отличие от случаев с 0 и 1 подтверждениями.

Answer (score -1):

Проблема решена. Может кому понадобится ответ решение проблемы.

1. В кабинете нажмите Настройки - Адреса - Импортированные адреса - Импортировать адреса
2. Потом вбейте туда bitcoin адрес, который был сгенерированный через api.

Половина работы сделана.

3. После импорта напротив адреса нажмите More Options - Расходовать
4. Дальше в окне перевода средств в поле получатель выберите ваш bitcoin адрес по умолчанию.

Готово

Если понадобится приватный ключ, идите в раздел Безопасность - Укажите Фразы для восстановления (12 слов) и запишите их.

Потом идете на сайт https://iancoleman.io/bip39/
В поле BIP39 Mnemonic - укажите ваши 12 фраз через пробел, ниже увидите сгенерированные адреса с публичным и приватным ключами.

Выберите свой адрес и скопируйте нужный ключ, если в списке мало адресов и вашего нет, поставьте больше записей для отображения поле внизу Show и укажите кол-во и потом нажмите more rows.

Мне это помогло, надеюсь еще кому то будет полезной информация)

Comment: Благодарю!!! Помогло